# SQL Dump to Excel

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I am dumping data into Excel using `OPENROWSET`.

Let's call that the "EXCEL DUMPFILE". I have set up multiple Excel files that reference data from the "DUMP FILE". Every time people go into the Excel files to use them the data is not pulling thru from the "EXCEL DUMP FILE" because the DUMP FILE isn't open. Barring creating a script in SQL to open all the files up and refresh and save is there something I can do to make this automatic so that we don't have to have any intervention for people to get the most current data?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered dumping the SQL data to an area all the excel users had access to?  Then they could all pull the data directly into excel.

Comment: How much data?  100KB, 50MB?

Comment: All users have access to the data where its at... For some reason they up up the files and the data doesnt pull thru when they open it.. I believe thye have to click ENABLE...  I want to by pass that so it just updates when opened..

Comment: Sunds like a job for SSIS.